# Shell script to display - Memory usage, Disk Usage and CPU Load?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

I want to diplay the Memory usage, Disk Usage and CPU Load in the following format:

```
Memory Usage: 33/512MB (6%)    
Disk usage: 4.2/20GB (23%) 
CPU Load: 0.01
```

So I started using the below script to do that but somehow it gives me an error

```
#!/bin/bash

free -m | awk 'NR==2{printf "Memory Usage: %s/%sMB (%.2f%)\n", $3,$2,$3*100/$2 }'
df -h | awk '$NF=="/"{printf "Disk Usage: %d/%dGB (%s)\n", $3,$2,$5}'
top -bn1 | grep load | awk '{printf "CPU Load: %.2f\n", $(NF-2)}'
```

Below is the error I get -

```
awk: run time error: not enough arguments passed to printf("Memory Usage: %s/%sMB (%.2f%)
")
        FILENAME="-" FNR=2 NR=2
```

I am running ubuntu 12.04. Any idea what's wrong?

**Update:-**

After running my below shell script -

```
#!/bin/bash

free -m | awk 'NR==2{printf "Memory Usage: %s/%sMB (%.2f%%)\n", $3,$2,$3*100/$2 }'
df -h | awk '$NF=="/"{printf "Disk Usage: %d/%dGB (%s)\n", $3,$2,$5}'
top -bn1 | grep load | awk '{printf "CPU Load: %.2f\n", $(NF-2)}'
```

I got below output -

```
Memory Usage: 128504/128896MB (99.70%)
Disk Usage: 3/48GB (8%)
CPU Load: 0.40
```

Does CPU Load looks ok? What does 0.40 means? And what number I should say will be high for CPU Load?

Comment: Use `uptime` instead of `top` to get load average.

Comment: WRT cpu load take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_%28computing%29 in my experience I saw some servers with 10-20 load and still responsive, in other cases load of 3-5 hanging

Comment: +1, The question contains more useful information than the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try escaping the `%`:

```
printf "Memory Usage: %s/%sMB (%.2f%%)\n"
```

Comment: Yup works fine. Thanks a lot. You were talking about using uptime instead of top? What is the difference between those two? And why you suggested to use uptime? Just trying to learn something new.

Comment: @AKIWEB why `uptime` instead of `top` run this `time uptime` `time top -b n 1` you will see that uptime is much faster because it does not check every single process metadata.

Comment: I see.. Can you provide an example how would that work with my above shell script if I need to use it?

Comment: @AKIWEB you can use this: `uptime  | awk '{printf "CPU Load: %.2f\n", $(NF-2)}' `

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yup it worked fine. Also what number in CPU Load means, the load is pretty high? Right now, it shows as 0.28 or 0.40? How do I know from which number it means the CPU Load is very high? I have updated the question.

Comment: `man uptime` : the numbers are the load averages over the last 1, 5, and 15 minutes.

Comment: This was the answer that solved my similar problem. I forgot `%%` escapes an awk `%`, not `\%` :)